# MS Access (via VB.NET) - convert linked attribute tables to columns in output

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've searched, and found a lot of similar things, but not quite what I'm looking for.

I have what are essentially a bunch of linked tables with attributes and values.

```
xxBio table

xxBio_ID    xxBio_LINK
1           100
2           101



xx table

xxBio_LINK  xxAttr_LINK
100         1000
101         2000



xxAttr table

xxAttr_LINK xxAttrCat_1_LINK    xxAttrCat_2_LINK
1000        null                550
2000        650                 null



xxAttrCat_1 table

xxAttrCat_1_LINK    xxAttrCat_1_Description     xxAttrCat_1_Value
650                 wumpus                      20


xxAttrCat_2 table

xxAttrCat_2_LINK    xxAttrCat_2_Description     xxAttrCat_2_Value
550                 frith                       30
```

OUTPUT NEEDS TO BE:

```
xxBio_ID    frith   wumpus
1           30      null
2           null    20
```

I can easily see how to get the result set with columns like attribute_name1, attribute_value1, attribute_name2, attribute_value2, and so forth.

```
SELECT xxBio.ID, xxAttrCat_1.xxAttrCat_1_Description, xxAttrCat_1.xxAttrCat_1_Value, xxAttrCat_2.xxAttrCat_2_Description, xxAttrCat_2.xxAttrCat_2_Value

FROM ((

(xx INNER JOIN xxBio ON xx.xxBio_LINK = xxBio.xxBio_LINK)

 INNER JOIN xxAttr ON xx.xxAttr_LINK = xxAttr.xxAttr_LINK)

 LEFT JOIN xxAttrCat_1 ON xxAttr.xxAttrCat_1_LINK = xxAttrCat_1.xxAttrCat_1_LINK)
 LEFT JOIN xxAttrCat_2 ON xxAttr.xxAttrCat_2_LINK = xxAttrCat_2.xxAttrCat_2_LINK
```

But that's not what we need. We need the attribute names to be column names.

How do we achieve this?

*Update to question:*
It turned out that we misunderstood the requirements, so we had to take a different route and did not get to try the answers. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the SQL in a string and execute from VBA.  (Dynamic SQL?)

```
sql = "SELECT xxBio.ID, " & xxAttrCat_1.xxAttrCat_1_Description & ", " & ...
```

Comment: Just thought about this.  This above would work to create your table, but then a subsequent pass would be required to write the records to that table, as per your example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`IIF()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) conditional statements:

```
SELECT xxBio.ID,     
       IIF(xxAttrCat_1.xxAttrCat_1_Description = 'wumpus',
           xxAttrCat_1.xxAttrCat_1_Value, NULL) As [wumpus], 
       IIF(xxAttrCat_2.xxAttrCat_2_Description = 'frith', 
           xxAttrCat_2.xxAttrCat_2_Value, NULL) As [frith]    
FROM (((xx 
INNER JOIN xxBio ON xx.xxBio_LINK = xxBio.xxBio_LINK)
INNER JOIN xxAttr ON xx.xxAttr_LINK = xxAttr.xxAttr_LINK)
LEFT JOIN xxAttrCat_1 ON xxAttr.xxAttrCat_1_LINK = xxAttrCat_1.xxAttrCat_1_LINK)
LEFT JOIN xxAttrCat_2 ON xxAttr.xxAttrCat_2_LINK = xxAttrCat_2.xxAttrCat_2_LINK
```

---

If each ID can have multiple values along same descriptions and you need to sum or average all corresponding values, then turn query into conditional aggregation (known as pivoting). Below also uses table aliases, `a`, `b`, `c1`, `c2` for brevity and organization.

```
SELECT b.ID,     
      SUM(IIF(c1.xxAttrCat_1_Description='wumpus', c1.xxAttrCat_1_Value, NULL)) As [wumpus], 
      SUM(IIF(c2.xxAttrCat_2_Description='frith', c2.xxAttrCat_2_Value, NULL)) As [frith]    
FROM (((xx 
INNER JOIN xxBio b ON xx.xxBio_LINK = b.xxBio_LINK)
INNER JOIN xxAttr a ON xx.xxAttr_LINK = a.xxAttr_LINK)
LEFT JOIN xxAttrCat_1 c1 ON a.xxAttrCat_1_LINK = c1.xxAttrCat_1_LINK)
LEFT JOIN xxAttrCat_2 c2 ON a.xxAttrCat_2_LINK = c2.xxAttrCat_2_LINK
GROUP BY b.ID
```

And if such descriptions can be many use MS Access SQL's [crosstab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192901.aspx) query. But since you have two categories, run a crosstab on each and save them as stored queries or views. Then, join together:

```
--CATEGORY 1
TRANSFORM SUM(c1.xxAttrCat_1_Value) AS SumOfValue
SELECT b.ID,                    
FROM ((xx 
INNER JOIN xxBio b ON xx.xxBio_LINK = b.xxBio_LINK)
INNER JOIN xxAttr a ON xx.xxAttr_LINK = a.xxAttr_LINK)
LEFT JOIN xxAttrCat_1 c1 ON a.xxAttrCat_1_LINK = c1.xxAttrCat_1_LINK
GROUP BY b.ID
PIVOT c1.xxAttrCat_1_Description;

--CATEGORY 2
TRANSFORM SUM(c2.xxAttrCat_2_Value) AS SumOfValue
SELECT b.ID,                    
FROM ((xx 
INNER JOIN xxBio b ON xx.xxBio_LINK = b.xxBio_LINK)
INNER JOIN xxAttr a ON xx.xxAttr_LINK = a.xxAttr_LINK)
LEFT JOIN xxAttrCat_2 c2 ON a.xxAttrCat_2_LINK = c2.xxAttrCat_2_LINK
GROUP BY b.ID
PIVOT c2.xxAttrCat_2_Description;

--CROSSTAB QUERIES JOIN
SELECT c1.*, c2.*
FROM Categ1CrossTabQ c1
INNER JOIN Categ1CrossTabQ c2
ON c1.ID = c2.ID;
```

*Please note: comments above with double dash are not allowed in an Access query and only one statement is allowed in saved query. Access has a limit of 255 columns per table/query, so pivoted values greater than 255 will err out unless you use `IN` clause. Finally, you cannot use crosstabs as subqueries. And crosstabs are strictly an MS Access command and not used in other DBMS's.*